# Do Facebook CPC ads charge per click, or per like, or both?

Tags: facebook, advertising

I'm about to create a Facebook campaign that points to our Facebook fan page, with the CPC option.

I want to know what counts as a "click".

I already read the docs (quickly to be honest), but i didn't get the answer.

Do they charge for the click which redirects to the fan page, or when the user clicks the like at the bottom of the ad, or both ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be charged for both types of click if you use CPC pricing.

Answer (score 1):

You can set them up to do it per click or per impression. If you go through their 'Add an advert' process, you will see this.